# showsPrec and operator precedences

Tags: string, haskell, operator-precedence

I asked about this before, but it seems I phrased the question too narrowly. So let's see if I can explain what I'm actually after.

Suppose I have some type that supports several binary operators, each with varying precedence and associativity. How do I write a `Show` instance that correctly brackets sub-expressions?

I know I'm being dense here, but I get this wrong *every single time* I try to do it. There must be some mechanical procedure you can follow to make this work out correctly, but I cannot find it. Can somebody walk me through an example?

I know this ultimately boils down to wrapping everything in `showParen`, and showing sub-expressions using `showsPrec` with the right magic number, and I can make it *almost* work, but it never quite works right in *all* circumstances.

---

**Edit:** Consider the following code

```
data Expr =
  Const Int |
  Expr :+: Expr |
  Expr :-: Expr |
  Expr :*: Expr |
  Expr :/: Expr

infixl 6 :+:
infixl 6 :-:
infixl 7 :*:
infixl 7 :/:

instance Show Expr where
  showsPrec p e0 =
    case e0 of
     Const n -> shows n
     x :+: y -> showParen (p > 6) $ (showsPrec 6 x) . (" :+: " ++) . (showsPrec 6 y)
     x :-: y -> showParen (p > 6) $ (showsPrec 6 x) . (" :-: " ++) . (showsPrec 6 y)
     x :*: y -> showParen (p > 7) $ (showsPrec 7 x) . (" :*: " ++) . (showsPrec 7 y)
     x :/: y -> showParen (p > 7) $ (showsPrec 7 x) . (" :/: " ++) . (showsPrec 7 y)
```

This *almost* works correctly:

```
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :*: Const 3 :+: Const 4
1 :+: 2 :*: 3 :+: 4
*Main> (Const 1 :+: Const 2) :*: (Const 3 :+: Const 4)
(1 :+: 2) :*: (3 :+: 4)
```

But not quite:

```
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: Const 3 :-: Const 4
1 :+: 2 :-: 3 :-: 4
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :-: Const 4)
1 :+: 2 :-: 3 :-: 4
```

So it looks like the *precedence* is OK, but the *associativity* is borked.

Comment: Google suggests these two questions: [Pretty Printing AST with Minimal Parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13708837/791604) and [Associativity and Precedence of Expressions when Generating C / C++ Code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4306680/791604). These may give you some ideas. I'm not sure whether this qualifies as a duplicate of one of those or not, but for now I lean towards "not a dup", since this question is in part about how to make the general techniques fit into the Haskell ecosystem smoothly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `showsPrec` hasn't any way to obtain the associativity of the context, I don't think it's possible to fix this as in, get exactly the minimal Haskell parenthesation back. To ensure correctness without adding more redundant parens than necessary, use `>=` in the `showParen` condition:

```
  showsPrec p e0 =
    case e0 of
     Const n -> shows n
     x :+: y -> showParen (p >= 6) $ (showsPrec 6 x) . (" :+: " ++) . (showsPrec 6 y)
     x :-: y -> showParen (p >= 6) $ (showsPrec 6 x) . (" :-: " ++) . (showsPrec 6 y)
     x :*: y -> showParen (p >= 7) $ (showsPrec 7 x) . (" :*: " ++) . (showsPrec 7 y)
     x :/: y -> showParen (p >= 7) $ (showsPrec 7 x) . (" :/: " ++) . (showsPrec 7 y)
```

This then yields

> *Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :*: Const 3 :+: Const 4
>   (1 :+: 2 :*: 3) :+: 4
>   *Main> (Const 1 :+: Const 2) :*: (Const 3 :+: Const 4)
>   (1 :+: 2) :*: (3 :+: 4)
>   *Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: Const 3 :-: Const 4
>   ((1 :+: 2) :-: 3) :-: 4
>   *Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :-: Const 4)
>   (1 :+: 2) :-: (3 :-: 4)

Which doesn't look quite as nice as it could, but not too bad and certainly not wrong like the `showParen (p > n)` version. Basically, this gives what would be the minimal parenthesization if we had only `infix`, no `infixl` or `infixr`.

If you want only those parens to appear which are really necessary, you'll need to propagate more information than just an `Int` for context fixity. I implemented that kind of thing [in my symbolic-math extension idea for HaTeX](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/Symbolic-math-HaTeX/blob/master/Math/LaTeX/Internal/MathExpr.hs#L85); essentially it just mirrors Haskell's `infixl` etc. annotations at runtime. For example,

```
     exaDisp $ 5 - (4 - 3) + 2 + 1
```

is then rendered like

[image: Minimal-parenthesization in HaTeXMath]

Answer (score 28):

The following `Show` instance will print the `Expr` type with minimal parentheses:

```
data Expr =
  Const Int |
  Expr :+: Expr |
  Expr :-: Expr |
  Expr :*: Expr |
  Expr :/: Expr

infixl 6 :+:
infixl 6 :-:
infixl 7 :*:
infixl 7 :/:

instance Show Expr where
  showsPrec p e0 =
    case e0 of
     Const n -> showParen (p > 10) $ showString "Const " . showsPrec 11 n
     x :+: y -> showParen (p > 6) $ showsPrec 6 x . showString " :+: " . showsPrec 7 y
     x :-: y -> showParen (p > 6) $ showsPrec 6 x . showString " :-: " . showsPrec 7 y
     x :*: y -> showParen (p > 7) $ showsPrec 7 x . showString " :*: " . showsPrec 8 y
     x :/: y -> showParen (p > 7) $ showsPrec 7 x . showString " :/: " . showsPrec 8 y
```

This results in:

```
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :*: Const 3 :+: Const 4
Const 1 :+: Const 2 :*: Const 3 :+: Const 4
*Main> (Const 1 :+: Const 2) :*: (Const 3 :+: Const 4)
(Const 1 :+: Const 2) :*: (Const 3 :+: Const 4)
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: Const 3 :-: Const 4
Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: Const 3 :-: Const 4
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :-: Const 4)
Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :-: Const 4)
```

The general rule is

- `infix n`: use `showParen (p > n)`, `showsPrec (n+1)` on the left, and `showsPrec (n+1)` on the right
- `infixl n`: use `showParen (p > n)`, `showsPrec n` on the left, and `showsPrec (n+1)` on the right
- `infixr n`: use `showParen (p > n)`, `showsPrec (n+1)` on the left, and `showsPrec n` on the right
- non-infix: use `showParen (p > 10)` and `showsPrec 11` on the arguments

Following this rule will always yield correct syntax with minimal parentheses, except in one corner case: It can produce ambiguous output if you have `infixl` and `infixr` constructors with the same precedence level. As long as you don't do that, you should be fine.

---

How did I know what arguments to use with `showParen`? It's to match what Haskell does for derived `Show` instances. We can test those like this:

```
data T = P :# P | T P
  deriving Show

infix 6 :#

data P = P

instance Show P where
  showsPrec p P = shows p
```

We can see that with `infix 6 :#`, the `Show T` instance calls `showsPrec 7` on the arguments to `:#`, and also it shows parentheses only at precedences > 6:

```
*Main> showsPrec 6 (P :# P) ""
"7 :# 7"
*Main> showsPrec 7 (P :# P) ""
"(7 :# 7)"
```

And for the ordinary constructor `T`, the generated instance calls `showsPrec 11` on the argument and shows parens at precedences > 10:

```
*Main> showsPrec 10 (T P) ""
"T 11"
*Main> showsPrec 11 (T P) ""
"(T 11)"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
prec :: Expr -> Int
prec (Const _) = 10
prec (_ :*: _) = 7
prec (_ :/: _) = 7
prec (_ :+: _) = 6
prec (_ :-: _) = 6

instance Show Expr where
  showsPrec p e0 =
    case e0 of
     Const n -> shows n
     x :+: y -> showbin 6 " + " x y
     x :-: y -> showbin 6 " - " x y
     x :*: y -> showbin 7 " * " x y
     x :/: y -> showbin 7 " / " x y
    where showbin pr s x y =
            showParen (p > pr) $
             showsPrec pr x . (s ++) .
             showParen (prec y == pr) (showsPrec pr y)
```

resulting in

```
*Main> (Const 1 :+: Const 2) :*: (Const 3 :+: Const 4)
(1 + 2) * (3 + 4)
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: Const 3 :-: Const 4
1 + 2 - 3 - 4
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :-: Const 4)
1 + 2 - (3 - 4)
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :-: Const 4 :-: Const 5)
1 + 2 - (3 - 4 - 5)
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :-: (Const 4 :-: Const 5))
1 + 2 - (3 - (4 - 5))
*Main> Const 1 :+: Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :*: (Const 4 :/: Const 5))
1 + 2 - 3 * (4 / 5)
*Main> (Const 1 :*: (Const 2 :-: (Const 3 :*: (Const 4 :/: Const 5))))
1 * (2 - 3 * (4 / 5))
```